# Не получается импортировать пакет psycopg 2.9.1 в проект python версии 2.7

Tags: импорт, python-2.7, psycopg2

Не получается импортировать пакет psycopg 2.9.1 в проект python версии 2.7,при соответствующей попытке импорта выскакивает предупреждение "Import "psycopg2" could not be resolved from source python 2.7.

Код программы:

```
import psycopg2
conn=psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    dbname="sender_logs",
    username="postgres")

curr=conn.cursor()
conn.close()
```

Comment: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#prerequisites - поддержка python 3.6+

Comment: спасибо,есть какой-то другой адаптер для связи с postgresql c помощью python2.7?

Comment: Погуглил и нашел такой список: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PostgreSQL Но не проверял, какие из указанных библиотек на python2 будут работать